# How to populate CKeditor with data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an update form which works fine, without the CKeditor, the textareas are populated with the content from the database.

I'm just trying to implement the CKeditor. I can type text in here and it will save to the database, but the text does not automatically populate into the CKeditor when I want to update.

Please can someone provide some help as to getting the content from the database into the CKeditor, just as it does into the textarea at the minute.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: login.php");
}  
//$vbCrLf = chr(13).chr(10);
    $vbCrLf = "";

    require ('mysqli.php');

 //create and execute query
    $query = 'SELECT PageId, PageTitle, PageContent, PageContent2 FROM pages ORDER BY PageId';
 $result = $conn->query($query);
    //create selection list
    $DropDownList = "<select name='PageId' id='PageId' onchange='SelectChanged();'> ".$vbCrLf;
    //Code below may need to be deleted
 $DropDownList .= "<option value=''>--SELECT PAGE--</option> ".$vbCrLf;
    // as it could give an error

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $heading = htmlentities($row[0]);
        $DropDownList .= "<option value='$heading'>".json_encode($row[1])."</option> ".$vbCrLf;
        $PageTitlePhp .= 'PageTitleArray['.$heading.']='.json_encode($row[1]).';'.$vbCrLf;
        $PageContentPhp .= 'PageContentArray['.$heading.']='.json_encode($row[2]).';'.$vbCrLf;
        $PageContent2Php .= 'PageContent2Array['.$heading.']='.json_encode($row[3]).';'.$vbCrLf;
    }

    $DropDownList .= "</select> ".$vbCrLf;
 $conn->close();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Update Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<br>
<!-- php below; Creates a form to update database content -->
<form  method="post"  action="update_website_page_handle.php">
<table width="943" height="528">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="32" colspan="2" align="left"><h1> Update Page </h1></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="60" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="134" height="32" align="left"><p>Select Page ID:</p></td>
    <td width="733">
        <?php echo $DropDownList; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><p>Page Title:</p></td>
    <td><textarea style="width: 500px; height: 50px;" name="PageTitle" id="PageTitle" class="heading"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><p>Page Content:</p></td>
    <td>
      <textarea style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" name="PageContent" id="PageContent" class="date"></textarea>  
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><p>Extra Page Content:</p></td>
    <td>
  <textarea style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" name="PageContent2" id="PageContent2" class="details"><?php print $PageContent2Php; ?></textarea>
     <script>
     CKEDITOR.replace('PageContent2');     
     </script>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <input name="update" type="submit"  id="update" value="Update">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var PageTitleArray = new Array();
    <?php echo $PageTitlePhp; ?>
    var PageContentArray = new Array();
    <?php echo $PageContentPhp; ?>
    var PageContent2Array = new Array();
    <?php echo $PageContent2Php; ?>
    function SelectChanged()
    {
        var PageId = document.getElementById('PageId').value;
        document.getElementById('PageTitle').value = PageTitleArray[PageId];
        document.getElementById('PageContent').value = PageContentArray[PageId];
        document.getElementById('PageContent2').value = PageContent2Array[PageId];
    }
    SelectChanged(); // added to execute the function after loading to select first value.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Write the content into a textarea and hook ckeditor up to the textarea.  What problems are you having with that?

Comment: In the code above, you can see that I have the ckeditor linked with the text area, but for some reason, the ckeditor isnt displaying the content from the database.